# How to make the search query more specific in Opencart? How to exclude keyword from product search in Opencart?

Tags: php, search, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I have a multi-category store: [https://www.gadgets-house.com](https://www.gadgets-house.com/)
I am selling batteries including AA battery and AAA battery, which are far different as per their functions.
Now, the issue is, whenever I am trying to search the AA battery search result includes AAA batteries as well. As "AA battery" intersect in the "AAA battery keyword" it shows me a mixed search.
Can anyone help me out to find only a specific keyword triggered products only? or is there any way to mark negative keywords in a specific product listing?
Opencart Version 2.3.0.2
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jessica, this is an interesting issue. You can have a look at how the search works in the `/catalog/controller/product/search.php` file. A quick glance shows that it's using the search phrase as a filter and not trying to match keywords specifically. You can obviously change this behaviour but may need to consider the potential consequences for other scenarios.

Comment: I checked the same but not worked for me.

Comment: What did you check? Are you able to share some of the code you've attempted already?

Comment: @JessicaSmith both are not working at the time. working individuals. if you are satisfied with my answer/ please upvote and mark it. it's very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes 100% possible:**

I was the complete task before a few months ago and tested in my live website.

[image]

[image]

> I have 2 keywords right now

1. AA shoes
2. AAA shoes

[image]

> **Step 1 : Go to catalog/model/catalog/product.php**

**find**

```
$implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$implode[] = "pd.name ='" . $this->db->escape($word) . "'";
```

**find**

```
$sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$sql .= " OR pd.description  ='" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "'";
```

> **Step 2 : Go to catalog/model/journal3/filter.php**

**find**

```
$implode[] = " pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$implode[] = " pd.name = '" . $this->db->escape($word) . "'";
```

**find**

```
$sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($filter_data['filter_name']) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$sql .= " OR pd.description = '" . $this->db->escape($filter_data['filter_name']) . "'";
```

**find**

```
$implode[] = "pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$implode[] = "pd.tag = '" . $this->db->escape($word) . "'";
```

**find**

```
$sql .= " pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($tag) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$sql .= " pd.tag = '" . $this->db->escape($tag) . "'";
```

**find**

```
$sql .= " OR pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($tag) . "%'";
```

**Replace with**

```
$sql .= " OR pd.tag = '" . $this->db->escape($tag) . "'";
```

Comment: please check my answer @Jessica Smith. i m waiting for your response.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion. But no luck. You can check at my website www.gadgets-house.com with 2 keywords: AA battery and AAA battery

Comment: yes it working on my website. you can see here https://www.inceptionsystem.com/bmc/

Comment: It is not working on your website as well. When I searched "aa shoes", it displays aa shoes and aaa shoes both.
Check at https://www.inceptionsystem.com/bmc/index.php?route=product/search&search=aa%20shoes&description=true

Comment: yes i wil update soon on search page. after i will inform you

Comment: i also update the answer here. check and inform to me

Comment: OCMOD for this would be ideal @MujahidBhoraniya

Comment: It is not working well. It matches the only exact keyword. If it will not there, it will not display any result. For example, I have just changed your query from "aa shoes" to "aa shoe" and found no result.
https://www.inceptionsystem.com/bmc/index.php?route=product/search&search=aaa%20shoe&description=true

Comment: @JessicaSmith that's why there's a wildcard `%` in the original select statements. Otherwise you need to have two search methods: 1. An exact match search & if there are no results 2. The standard search.